# Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с функцией в модели Django

Tags: django

```
class Book(models.Model):
    #модель, которая описывает общую книгу, а не конкретную
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    summary =models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Enter a breaf description on book')
    isbn = models.CharField('ISBN',max_length=13,help_text='13 Character <a href="https://www.isbn-international.org>">ISBN number</a>')
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text='Select a genre for this book')
    language = models.ForeignKey('Language', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    def str(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('book-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def display_genre(self):
        return ' '.join([genre.name for genre in self.genre.all()[:3]])#не понимаю
    display_genre.short_description = 'Genre' #не понимаю

    def display_language(self):
        return ' '.join([language.name for language in self.genre.all()[:4]]) #не понимаю
        display_genre.short_description = 'Language'#не понимаю
```

Для чего нужны функции `def display_genre(self)` и `def display_language(self)`, точнее, что они возвращают (прошу прощения, если вопрос задан некорректно) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражение `display_genre.short_description = 'Genre'` присваивает методу атрибут, что позволит потом в админке использовать его как поле и отображать в заголовке колонки "Genre", а не "display_genre".

Чтобы понимать выражение `' '.join([language.name for language in self.genre.all()[:4]])` нужно изучить [списковые включения](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Данное выражение возвращает строку, состоящую из  первых 3 имён жанров, разделённых пробелом.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @OmertaOmerta [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).